# Could not download Excel sheet using Angularjs $http service

Tags: node.js, angularjs, excel

While I am running the URL(`i.e-http://localhost:3002/api/downloadFeedback`) on browser directly it can be downloaded but when I am using angular `$http` service its returning the binary data.I am using node.js for backend.

I am providing my code below.

```
   var userData={"month":parseInt($scope.month),"year":parseInt($scope.year)};
            var url='/api/downloadFeedback';
            var method='GET';
            var token=$window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            //console.log('token',token);
            DataService.connectToServerSideScript(method,url,userData,token)
            .then(function(response) {
    }
    },function(error) {
                //alert(error['msg']);
            })

    function DataService($http, $q){
        return{
            connectToServerSideScript:connectToServerSideScript
        }
        function connectToServerSideScript(method,url,userData,authtoken=''){
            //console.log('deffered',method,url,userData);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method:method,
                url:url,
                data:userData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': authtoken }
            }).then(function(response) {
                //console.log('data defer',response.data);
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error.data);
            })
            //console.log('data defer',deferred.promise);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
```

My server side code is given below.

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    //res.send(allids);
                    var workbook = new excel.Workbook();
                    var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('MySheet');
                    /*sheet.autoFilter = {
                        from: 'A',
                        to: 'L'
                    }*/
                    sheet.columns = [
                        { header: 'ALLOCATED TO', key: 'allocated_to', width: 10 },
                        { header: 'ZONE', key: 'zone', width: 10 },
                        { header: 'STATE', key: 'state', width: 10 },
                        { header: 'LOCATION', key: 'location', width: 15 },
                        { header: 'ZONAL COLLECTION MANAGER', key: 'zonal_collection_manager', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'AREA COLLECTION MANAGER', key: 'area_collection_manager', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'COLLECTION MANAGER', key: 'collection_manager', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'FIELD AGENCY NAME', key: 'field_agency_name', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'FOS', key: 'fos', width: 15 },
                        { header: 'LOGIN ID', key: 'login_id', width: 27 },
                        { header: 'CL CONTRACT ID', key: 'cl_contract_id', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'LK LOAN ACCOUNT ID', key: 'lk_loan_account_id', width: 20 },
                        { header: 'DISPOSITION CODE', key: 'disposition_code', width: 18 },
                        { header: 'PROMISE DATE', key: 'promise_date', width: 18 },
                        { header: 'REMARK', key: 'other_remarks', width: 18 },
                        { header: 'REMARK DATE TIME', key: 'addedOn', width: 18 }
                    ];
                    allids.forEach(function(item){
                        sheet.addRow(item);
                    })
                    var dt = dateTime.create();
                    var formatted = dt.format('Y-m-d-H-M-S');
                    var filepath=formatted+'_download';
                    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./uploads/Excel/'+filepath+'.xlsx').then(function(){
                        console.log("file is written");
                    })
                    var tempFilePath = tempfile('.xlsx');
                    console.log("tempFilePath : ", tempFilePath);
                    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function() {
                        var filename=filepath+'.xlsx';
                        var filePath='./uploads/Excel/';
                        var fileLocation = path.join('./uploads/Excel/',filename);
                        var filet = __dirname+'/' + fileLocation;
                        console.log('filelocation',__dirname);
                        var dip_code='Content-disposition';
                        var attch='attachment; filename='+filename;
                        res.setHeader(dip_code, attch);
                        //res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.xlsx');
                        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                        res.download(fileLocation,filename);
                        //res.send(allids);
                    });
                }, 2000);
```

Here I can generate the Excel sheet and successfully write inside the folder. When directly running through browser same URL is downloading the file but when I am using the `$http` service its returning the some binary unreadable data in response. I need to also download the sheet using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

please add `responseType: "arraybuffer"`

in your `$http` option object as follows

```
$http({ 
  method:method, 
  url:url, 
  data:userData, 
  responseType: "arraybuffer", 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': authtoken } 
})
```